# dojo xhrPost progress (callback) event listener?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

In the dojo API documentation I can find callbacks for `load` and `error` but I am missing a callback for `progress`.

```
load: function(data) {
    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form posted.";
},
error: function(error) {
    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Error...";
}
```

The [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) API provides the possibility, to register event listeners for the `progress` event:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);

oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);

oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);

oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);

oReq.open();

// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {...}
```

Has dojo some mechanism, similar to the XMLHttpRequest API?

Comment: Have a look at the [dojo.xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/xhr.html) document. It mentions how progress event can be handled only if the browser supports those events.

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for xhrPost? It's a deprecated API and I can't even find it anymore.

Comment: @Leftium: Oh yes, you're right. xhrPost is deprecated http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/xhrPost.html#dojo-xhrpost-supported-object-properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *new* [`dojo/request`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request.html) module supports progress events. It will automatically call the new [dojo/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/xhr.html) module on browser platforms.

Don't confuse these API's with the old, deprecated, counterparts. There are key differences in the way the modules are included and called:

1. Different files must be included in a different manner (AMD instead of `require(dojo.*)`)
2. The methods must be called differently and return different types. The new request API uses promises instead of callbacks.

Use the following guides to convert your code to the new API (may require updating to a more recent version of Dojo):

- [Dojo migration guide: XHR and IO Requests](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html#xhr-and-io-requests) (Side-by-side comparison of old-style and new-style code)
- [Introducing dojo/request](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/08/21/introducing-dojorequest/)

---

**update:** If you *must* use Dojo 1.6...

You have two options:

1. Use a more modern Dojo next to Dojo 1.6 only for the part that needs the `progress` event. The new AMD architecture means the new library is isolated to the `require()` callback's block. AMD architecture also means you can load only the minimal parts of the modern Dojo required for the new xhr.
2. Backport the `progress` event feature to Dojo 1.6. You can add another callback and the [code doesn't seem that complex](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.10/request/xhr.js#L112-L121). (Don't forget to account for differences because you're not using promises.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and the two useful links). I have one big problem,  at the moment I have to deal with dojo 1.6 :(

Comment: @GeorgKastenhofer: That's too bad... I updated my answer with some suggestions for you.

Comment: Thanks for your further investigation. I hope we will update our server in the next month, otherwise I will follow one of your advices.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [dojo/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/xhr.html) document. It mentions how progress event can be handled only if the browser supports those events.

Following is a code snippet from the documentation.

**dojo/request/xhr()** returns a **promise** that is fulfilled with the handled data of the response. Errors will be directed to the errback if provided. **Progress** data will be given to the **progress handler** if it is provided and if the browser supports **XHR2 progress events**.

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr){
  xhr("example.json", {
    handleAs: "json"
  }).then(function(data){
    // Do something with the handled data
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  }, function(evt){
    // Handle a progress event from the request if the
    // browser supports XHR2
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one big problem, at the moment I have to deal with dojo 1.6 :(